# Are people making a mistake when they say that static files are .html, .js etc?

Tags: html, http, ssl, web-applications, server

I've been confused by the whole notion of a static vs. dynamic file.

Some people say that a "static" file is a file like index.html or some_style.css. But is this really true?

Isn't the whole notion of a static vs. dynamic files all about the way the file is GENERATED? `index.html` can be generated dynamically, using a web server which reaches out to some database, a bunch of APIs etc.  Thus, `index.html` can be a dynamic, not a static file. Same about a file like `some_js.js`.

So when you say a "dynamic file", or a "static file", you're inferring to the PROCESS by which that file was generated. The file itself (its name, extensions etc.) is not relevant to whether the file is static or dynamic.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the whole notion of a static vs. dynamic files all about the way the file is GENERATED?

Yes.

> Some people say that a "static" file is a file like index.html or some_style.css. But is this really true?

Those are examples of things which are **typically** static files.